# Django WSGI: no module named 'my_app.settings' while running wsgi.py from command line

Tags: python, django, modulenotfounderror

I've looked carefully through all similar questions on stackoverflow but found no working solution.
I have a problem running wsgi.py file due to the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'magic_orb.settings' (I'm creating a magic orb with predictions based on AstroGPT). My wsgi.py file looks like this:

```
import os
import sys

proj_path = ("../magic_orb")
sys.path.append(proj_path)

os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true"

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "magic_orb.settings")

os.chdir(proj_path)

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

As you may see, I've already tried changing the path and adding get_wsgi_application. Moreover, I've added `django.setup()` to the manage.py file as my main problem is with app loading. My project's structure is the following:

```
magic_orb
├── db.sqlite3
├── frontpage
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_frontpage.py
│   │   ├── 0002_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── magic_orb
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── magic_orb_model
│   ├── pretrained_model.py
│   └── __pycache__
├── manage.py
└── user_data_form
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   ├── 0002_user_data_form.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    ├── models.py
    ├── __pycache__
    ├── serializers.py
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

I am at a loss and have no idea what else I can do and how else to reformat the code/what else to add. Ready to provide additional details.

Error while trying to execute wsgi.py:

```
  File ~/django_servers/magic_orb/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File ~/django_servers/magic_orb/magic_orb/magic_orb/wsgi.py:23
    application = get_wsgi_application()

  File ~/django_servers/magic_orb/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py:12 in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)

  File ~/django_servers/magic_orb/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py:19 in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)

  File ~/django_servers/magic_orb/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py:102 in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)

  File ~/django_servers/magic_orb/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py:89 in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)

  File ~/django_servers/magic_orb/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py:217 in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)

  File /usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126 in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1050 in _gcd_import

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1027 in _find_and_load

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1004 in _find_and_load_unlocked

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'magic_orb.settings'
```

Error while trying to execute frontpage/models.py, which led me to modify wsgi.py

```
File ~/django_servers/magic_orb/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File ~/django_servers/magic_orb/magic_orb/frontpage/models.py:6
    class Prediction(models.Model):

  File ~/django_servers/magic_orb/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:129 in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)

  File ~/django_servers/magic_orb/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:260 in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()

  File ~/django_servers/magic_orb/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:138 in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")

AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

With an absolute path, the error is the same and sys.path is the following:

```
    print(sys.path)
['/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '', '/home/shbshka/django_servers/magic_orb/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/home/shbshka/django_servers/magic_orb', '/magic_orb/magic_orb', '/magic_orb/..', '/magic_orb/.', '/magic_orb/', '/home/shbshka/django_servers/magic_orb/magic_orb/magic_orb/../..', '/home/shbshka/django_servers/magic_orb/magic_orb/magic_orb/..', '/home/shbshka/django_servers/magic_orb/magic_orb/magic_orb/../..', '/home/shbshka/django_servers/magic_orb/magic_orb/magic_orb/..', '/home/shbshka/django_servers/magic_orb/magic_orb/magic_orb/../..', '/home/shbshka/django_servers/magic_orb/magic_orb/magic_orb/..', '/home/shbshka/django_servers/magic_orb/magic_orb/magic_orb/../..', '/home/shbshka/django_servers/magic_orb/magic_orb/magic_orb/..', '/home/shbshka/django_servers/magic_orb/magic_orb/magic_orb/../..', '/home/shbshka/django_servers/magic_orb/magic_orb/magic_orb/..', '../magic_orb/..', '../magic_orb', '../magic_orb', '../magic_orb', '../magic_orb', '../magic_orb', '/home/shbshka/django_servers/magic_orb/magic_orb', '/home/shbshka/django_servers/magic_orb/magic_orb', '/home/shbshka/django_servers/magic_orb/', '/home/shbshka/django_servers/magic_orb/']
```

---

Django `4.2.2`

Python `3.10.6`

Comment: please add the full error trace to your post. The error seams about searching "my_app.settings"  which is not the problem of wsgi.py as it does not appear there in your code.

Comment: sorry maybe misunderstanding as you mention another error message in the text about  magic_orb.settings

Comment: @Razenstein both errors added with explanations (I want to deal with the wsgi error first and it's the main focus of this question)

Comment: obviously your are launching wsgi,py as an python app from command line?  wsgi.py is a wsgi interface that is intended to be run from a webserver with wsgi interface. In development you would typically use the django built in server like "python manage.py runserver"

Comment: why do you want to run frontpage/models.py directly? what is the intention of your project?

Comment: @aaron I am launching it as a python app from command line as I'm doing debugging. When trying to make migrations, I receive an error django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration frontpage.0001_frontpage dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('frontpage', '0001_initial'), so I decided to run all dependent files one by one to identify the error.

Comment: Sorry, new to django, if I can't do that, would be grateful for an explanation

Comment: It should be `sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent))`. As for your problem with `django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError`, remove `('frontpage', '0001_initial')` from frontpage/migrations/0001_frontpage.py (or did you for some reason rename 0001_initial.py to 0002_initial.py and 0002_frontpage.py to 0001_frontpage.py?).

Comment: @aaron Oh god, I am stoopid, of course it should be 0002_initial, it just generated in a reversed sequence, thank you so much! I'll rename it rn.

Comment: @aaron I have recreated the files and now everything works perfectly well. Thanks again! Now the question - why can't I run wsgi.py separately?

Comment: @Anna You can run the file, it just won't serve requests without a server implementation, which accepts connections and passes requests to the `application` handler. The issue here though was that you weren't appending an appropriate path to `sys.path` from which to import your settings.

Answer (score 2):

first I would try to add the absolute path to sys.path:

```
sys.path.append("D:/......../magic_orb")              # path to project base dir, not the magic_orb in which you have settings.py 

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "magic_orb.settings")
```

Once this is working you can try to modify with path relative to working dir etc.
I would also add for debugging:

```
print("******* sys.path: ", sys.path)
```

Comment: It does not work with the same error, debugging is about to be added into the question

Comment: Reviewed your comment and noticed a comment mark there. It did not fix the issue, but this is a useful remark. Marked your answer as useful. Thanks!